# Можно ли на JavaScript написать генератор настоящих случайных чисел?

Tags: javascript

Math.random насколько мне известно возвращает псевдослучайные числа. Одна из моих идей по генерации настоящих случайных чисел заключалась в том, чтобы засекать очень маленькие отрезки времени, которые будут давать погрешность. Я пробовал написать такое, но правда был разочарован тем, что засекаемые значения времени повторялись очень часто и это не было похоже на генерацию случайных чисел. Может быть у вас есть какие нибудь интересные идеи? Вопрос теоретический и не носит практического применения, наверно. Спасибо.

Из википедии: Источники настоящих случайных чисел найти крайне трудно. Физические шумы, такие, как детекторы событий ионизирующей радиации, дробовой шум в резисторе или космическое излучение, могут быть такими источниками.

Comment: так как код программы в целом детерминированный, то написать генератор абсолютно случайных чисел нельзя. Но если привлекать сторонние средства (электронные генераторы) или скачивать с внешних ресурсов, то все можно.

Comment: @KoVadim Я сейчас подумал, а что если просто получать посделние миллисекунды при помощи Date.now()? Чем не генератор настоящих случайных чисел?

Comment: Если нужно получить одно число, то может оно и будет как бы случайным (если его получаем в результате клика пользователя по кнопке). Но это ведь не генератор. Но Date.now может выдавать значение квантированные и вполне возможно, что у Вас будет получаться всегда 03 или 98. 

Рекомендую взять книгу Кнута, второй том, третья глава и почитать. Многие вопросы уйдут сами.

Comment: Для javascript особенно подходит https://www.random.org/ , используется атмосферный шум (если не врут). Вы можете также собрать младшие биты оцифровки сигнала с микрофона или вебкамеры за несколько секунд, и далее использовать его как зерно для ГПСЧ (хотя это и не всегда будет работать как задумано).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Случайное число - это число, которое не поддается описанию. А ты в джаваскрипт коде будешь его описывать. Это противоречит определению случайного числа. Но можно высчитать псевдослучайное ("типа случайное") число. Как именно - сам не знаю. Так и реализованы все генераторы псевдослучайных чисел, в том числе и Math.random() - они считают не случайное, а трудно предсказуемое число.

Насчет даты - я сам такой генератор сделал недавно, решил написать простенькие игры на джаваскрипте. Мне надо было каждый раз, когда по ячейкам игрового поля бегаю, получать "типа случайное" число и на его основании делать вывод, что именно делать с конерктной ячейкой игрового поля. Миллисекунды мгновенные забирал,   обрабатывал их (например, брал остаток от деления на 2, то есть, выяснял, четное число или нечетное число миллисекунду у меня в руках). Мне поначалу показался вариант очень классным, ведь я не знаю, сколько миллисекунд в конкретный момент времени набегает. Но получается фигня в итоге, и сейчас объясню, почему. Браузер очень быстро все считает. Если запихать этот код "генератора" в функцию и таким образом "генерировать" (высчитывать) "типа случайные" числа подряд (то есть, вызывать эту функцию подряд, вызов за вызовом), то браузер будет делать несколько проходов по этой функции меньше, чем за 1 миллисекунду. Можешь сам попробовать, и в итоге ты будешь получать случайные числа "одинаковыми пачками", например, 5 раз четное число, 4 раза нечетное число.... Первый вариант, который я придумал был нагрузить браузер вычислениями внутри функции, чтобы он дольее считал. Я запихал туда вычисления *огромного* факториала, меняя который, регулировал время работы функции. Но надо было еще регулировать вероятность события, которые эта функция выдает. Вероятность моего события была 1/2 примерно. Чтобы добиться 1/6, надо было 3 раза функцию запускать с этим факториалом. В итоге, да, функция работала, как мне надо и выдавала нужную мне вероятность. Но пробежаться таким образом по всем ячейкам игрового поля занимает много времени - около секунды. Так никто вообще не делает. Ведь браузер - однопотоковый. А я занимаю его вычислениями на целую секунду. Это не вариант. Будет все остальное тормозить.

Еще вариант, который я сделал - можно число этих миллисекунд в строку перевести и "достать" каждый разряд. И что-то с ним сделать. Но, все равно - браузер будет выдавать серии одинаковых миллисекунд. Которые надо как-то отсеять.

Если подумать хорошо, то , я думаю, можно найти вариант. Сейчас придумал немного другой вариант, не знаю будет ли он работать, как надо. Каждый раз, когда я получаю "0" или "1" генератором, я запихиваю это дело в массив (i). Потом опять получаю псевдо случайную единицу или ноль (i+1). И закидываю в массив случайных чисел. Потом получаю третье число ноль или 1 (i+2). Если все три этих числа шли в одной "партии", которая успела просчитаться меньше, чем за 1 миллисекунду, то они будут одинаковые. Берем, например, второе и третье и удаляем. В массиве остается только одно число. Прогоняем еще раз функцию и забиваем в массив опять три переменные. Если они все одинаковые, то последние две удаляем... И так далее. Забивается массив со случайными числами "1" и "0". Таким образом, я думаю можно уменьшить повторяемость одинакового результата в серии вызовов функции-генератора. Короче, надо просто пробовать.